# TypeScript - pass hash table as an argument to PowerShell script

Tags: javascript, typescript, hashtable

In typescript, I'm trying to pass hash table as an argument to PowerShell script I'm calling.

Here is my typescript

```
let params = new Map();
params.set('Project', 'Testproject')
params.set('Username', 'John')
params.set('Password', 'Doe')

let script: string = path.join(__dirname, 'Test.ps1');
let command: string = `& ${pathToScriptPSString(script)} ${params}`
```

Test.ps1 script has 3 parameters: Project, Username, and Password.

In PowerShell, this is how I would do.

```
$paramsPassed = @{
    Test = "hello";
    Boolean = $true;
}


function test {

param(
    [parameter()]
    [string] $Test,
    [parameter()]
    [boolean] $Boolean
)

    Write-Host $Test
    Write-Host $Boolean
}


Test @paramsPassed
```

In the typescript, I tried these but didn't work.

```
let command: string = `& ${pathToScriptPSString(script)} ${params}`

let command: string = `& ${pathToScriptPSString(script)} @{params}`
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: That's not going to work. `params` will be converted to a string. I suggest you reevaluate your entire approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to convert `params` to a parameter string for PowerShell like below.

```
let params = new Map();
params.set('Project', 'Testproject')
params.set('Username', 'John')
params.set('Password', 'Doe')

function toPowerShellParams(params) {
   let paramsString = ''
   params.forEach((key, value) => paramString += `-${key} ${value} `)
   return paramString
}

let script: string = path.join(__dirname, 'Test.ps1');
let command: string = `& ${pathToScriptPSString(script)} ${toPowerShellParams(params)}`
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If i wanted to add a boolean type in the maps, would it be best to just do 
let command: string = `& ${pathToScriptPSString(script)} ${toPowerShellParams(params)} -Check $true`